# Can't get discord bot to mention author (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
      return

  if message.content.startswith('!play'):
      await message.channel.send('{author.mention} wants to play a game, would you like to play? @here')
```

I'm new to this, so please explain what I did wrong.

Comment: You are missing an `f"{author.mention}..."` in the f-string

Comment: I assume you're using discord.py, so I added the [tag:discord.py] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit]. BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
  if message.content.startswith('!play'):
      await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} wants to play a game, would you like to play? @here')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    author=ctx.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hey @here! {author.mention} wants to play a game! would you like to join them?')
```

im assuming you want this to be a command, so it will check for a prefix to call a function instead of using an `if` statement in the `on_message` event.